# A numeric type data field appears as 66de63.... How could it be changed to the correct data type?

Tags: string, google-bigquery, int64, datafield

I tried to use the cast function to change the data type, but
No matching signature for operator = for argument types: STRING, INT64. Supported signature: ANY = ANY

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.